# Fail to deploy Metro JAX-WS Web Service to Weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, maven, weblogic, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS web service deployed to a Weblogic 12c server. I'm using Eclipse for development and I have a Maven project where I created the web service. Until now it is working fine.

Now I want to add a security policy (UsernameToken) to it. As such, I've added the maven dependency for the Metro project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to deploy, I get the following stack trace:

```java
<30/Out/2013 12H32m WET> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1383136332821" for task "7". Error is: "

Unable to deploy EJB: webservices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar from webservices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:

[HTTP:101216]Servlet: "WSEE_SERVLET" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/ServiceImpl".
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.util.CertificateRetriever.getEndpointOROperationalLevelPolicy(CertificateRetriever.java:341)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.util.CertificateRetriever.checkforEPRIdentity(CertificateRetriever.java:224)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.IdentityEPRExtnContributor.getEPRExtension(IdentityEPRExtnContributor.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:210)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory$WLSEndpointImpl.<init>(WLSContainer.java:611)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(WLSContainer.java:564)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:601)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:183)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:139)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:68)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:624)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:565)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WseeWebappModule.activate(WseeWebappModule.java:151)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEEjbModule.activate(WSEEEjbModule.java:446)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.AppDeploymentExtensionFactory.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFactory.java:112)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.AppDeploymentExtensionFactory.access$200(AppDeploymentExtensionFactory.java:15)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.AppDeploymentExtensionFactory$1.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFactory.java:186)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)


"
```

Can someone give some thoughts on this?

Comment: I wonder if you did find an answer?

Comment: @olek I don't think so, and I don't really remember what I did (it was 5 years ago).

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic has it's own WS implementation. Better use scope provided to prevent deploy of metro-version:

`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`